# Is my plan to replace a 3-way dimmer switch with new 3-way rocker switch suitable?

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch

I am replacing a 3-way dimmer with a 3-way rocker switch which has the 2 gold-colored screws, one brassy/black screw, and the ground screw.

I just want to confirm something, or allow someone to correct me before I do this: In this case the black wire from this old dimmer would be power (dark screw), right? So on my new switch I would put the black wire to the dark screw, red and white to the gold screws, and then my ground?

Again, just want to confirm or allow for any critiques and education as i've replaced hundreds of standard single pole switches but only a handful of 3-ways and they were basically just copying from one to the other.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: That seems right on target, given one has to guess a bit with the undocumented but you know it's 3-way device, so you make the reasonable assumption that the black wire = the black screw and the red wires = the brass/gold screws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is corrected. You picked the Identified screw and are matching them. The other two are not important they will work each way.